# Помогите с SQL запросом. Двойной GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не могу сообразить какой запрос сделать для моих целей:

## Таблица

```
 
match_id   com_n   count
1597         1        2
1597         2        3
1598         1        3
1598         2        3
1599         1        2
1599         2        4
...         ...      ...
```

Первый столбец - id матча. Второй - номер команды. Третий - количество запитых голов. Например в первой строке В матче с id 1597 первая команда забила 2, а вторая 3 мяча.

## Запрос

Нужен такой запрос, который выведет количество ничей. Например матч с id 1598 был ничейным.

#### Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если гарантируется, что на каждый матч строго 2 записи (не больше и не меньше), то никакого двойного group by не надо. группируете по id матча и проверяете `having max(count)=min(count)` максимальное количество в группе может быть равно минимальному только если у вас ничья

Comment: *Если гарантируется, что на каждый матч строго 2 записи* Это можно отследить по `HAVING ... AND COUNT(*) = 2` (а по-хорошему, надо ещё чекать, что команд две, а не одна два раза)... Ибо считать "косячные" матчи стопудово не нужно

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Почти всегда на матч по 2 записи, но иногда бывает только 1 запись (то есть забивала только одна команда). Но не больше двух! Данные команды работают, только я не понимаю, что значит **(а по-хорошему, надо ещё чекать, что команд две, а не одна два раза)** ... А кажется понял. Если на один матч 2 записи, то гарантированно это разные команды. Можете оформлять ответ.

Comment: *иногда бывает только 1 запись (то есть забивала только одна команда).* Ага... и ноль записей, если ни одна из команд не забивала... не? кстати, при такой петрушке простым MIN/MAX уже не обойтись... *Если на один матч 2 записи, то гарантированно это разные команды* Это поддержано соответствующим констрейнтом? или так, типа "софт не позволит"? так вот - гарантирую, позволит.

Comment: Да. Но таких записей просто нет. То есть в таблице теряется информация о матчах 0-0. Такие ничьи не найти данными командами, но мне это не нужно!

Comment: 1) Судя по имени столбца `count` вы в вопросе привели не таблицу, а результат запроса. Покажите, пожалуйста, структуру таблицы. 2) Есть ли таблица с самими матчами?

Comment: Есть таблица с матчами. У каждого матча есть уникальный id, название команд дата и время матча и т.д. И есть таблица с голами. У каждого гола есть id матча, номер забившей команды и время забитого мяча. Это все данные которые есть. Мне надо получить количество ничей до N-ной минуты (счет 0-0 не принципиально). Комменты выше удовлетворяют моей задаче.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Двойная групировка - идет через запятую  `group by n,m`

То-есть

```
 select a, b, count(*) ct from table1 group by com_n,count
```

Ну и хотим ничью - вот

```
 select a,b, count(*) ct from table1 
 where a = b
 group by a,b
```

Осталось мелочь - привести таблицу к счёт1 = a и счёт2 = b.

```
 select a.count, b.count, count(*) ct from table2 a
  inner join table2 b 
  on a.match_id = b.match_id  and a.com_n <> b.com_n   
 where a.count = b.count
 group by a.count, b.count
```

При "нормальных" условиях (нету дублей, затроений и т п) результат будет хороший. Можно добавить групировку по матчу - тогда будет извесно какие айди матча выиграли.

Если ответ - одно число... стоп...
А теперь прикол - групировка... heaving в данном случае не нужна вообще. Посмотрел я на монстра выше, и решил "сократить" групировки... так

```
 select * from table2 a
  inner join table2 b 
  on a.match_id = b.match_id  
  and a.com_n <> b.com_n  
  and a.count = b.count
```

Или одним числом - заменив `*` на `count(*)`